# getJson in test in laravel does not get passed to controller

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have a test in a Laravel project where I do a getJson request and some answer should be returned. But the method in the controller doesn't get hit.

The test

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class NotificationsTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->signIn();
    }




    public function test_a_user_can_fetch_their_unread_notifications()
    {

        create(DatabaseNotification::class);

        $response = $this->getJson(url('/profiles') . '/' . auth()->user()->name . '/notifications')->json();

        $this->assertCount(1, $response);
    }
```

The line in webp.php that should process this request:

```
Route::get('/profiles/{user}/notifications', 'UserNotificationsController@index');
```

The UserNotificationsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;

class UserNotificationsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middelware('auth');
    }

    public function index() {
        dd(" UsderNotificationsController-Index method hit");
        return auth()->user()->unreadNotifications;
    }


    public function destroy(User $user, $notificationId)
    {

        dd(' Destroy method hit');
        auth()->user()->notifications()->findOrFail($notificationId)->markAsRead();
    }
}
```

If I run the test with phpunit, I would expect that the DD() in the index method should be executed. But it doesn't.

I tried all kinds of variations to generate the URI, but always get the same result. Can anyone tell me why I do not generate the correct URI?

Kind regards,

HUbert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //start by doing that : in your controller
Route::get('/profiles/notifications', 'UserNotificationsController@index');

  public function test_a_user_can_fetch_their_unread_notifications()
 {
   $this->withoutHandlingException();

    create(DatabaseNotification::class,['user_id'=>$this->signIn()->id]);
     $this->signIn()//i think it should return authenticated user

    $response = $this->get('/profiles/notifications')
                ->assertStatus(200);
   // $this->assertCount(1, $response);
    
}
```

-//in your index function

```
public function index() {
    dd(" UsderNotificationsController-Index method hit");
    return response()->json(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications,200);
}
```